# Why does my application exit with a "SIGABRT"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-simulator

I am working on an iPhone application that will receive a grocery shopping list as xml from a REST HTTP service. But when I run the application, it exits with a SIGABRT in the simulator.

I can see from the stack trace that I am inside [NSAutoreleasePool release], so I guess it is a memory management issue. The problem with the autorelease pool is of course that it can be very difficult to trace what is the actual problem.

I have however found out that it is somehow caused by a call to [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest], because if I place my return statement just before that call, then I get no error (except there is no data). If I place my return statement just after the sendSynchronousRequest, then I get the SIGABRT.

Here is the function

```
- (NSArray*)getShoppingListItems {
    NSString *escapedToken = [self.user.token URLEncodedString_ch];
    NSString *strUrl = [[NSString alloc] 
                        initWithFormat:@"http://www.denglademad.dk/shoppinglist/foruser/%@?token=%@",
                        self.user.userID, escapedToken];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:strUrl] ;
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    NSURLResponse *resp = nil;
    NSError *err = nil;
    // Returning [NSMutableArray array] does not cause SIGABRT
    NSData *response = [[NSURLConnection 
                        sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest 
                        returningResponse: &resp
                        error: &err] retain];
    // Returning here does cause a SIGABRT
    return [NSMutableArray array]; 
    NSString *xml = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    ShoppingListXmlParser *parser = [[ShoppingListXmlParser alloc] init];
    return [parser parseShoppingListXmlData:response];
}
```

I know there's a lot of stuff that should be release, but seing this is an autorelease problem, I just removed every release/autorelease call temporarily in desperation.

Here is the output from the debugger.

```
...
Canceling call as the malloc lock is held so it isn't safe to call the runtime.
Issue the command:
    set objc-non-blocking-mode off 
to override this check if you are sure your call doesn't use the malloc libraries or the ObjC runtime.
(gdb) continue
DenGladeMad(619,0xa0c51540) malloc: *** error for object 0x4d3cd40: double free
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
(gdb)
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

This is generally an error related to releasing an unallocated object.  Try setting `NSZombieEnabled = YES` on your target's Executable.  Just double-click the executable in Xcode, choose the arguments tab and set this under the Environment Variables section on the lower-half of the properties window.  This will give you a lot more detail in the ogs the next time you hit it in the simulator.

Be sure to disable this variable before building and submitting your app.  There are a lot of resources consumed when it is on, so your app will suffer a performance hit.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Setting the variable shows the message: -[NSConcreteMutableData release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x26b4dfe0 (with different address for each run). Any idea how I figure out which object hides behind that address

Comment: NSConcreteMutableData is the specific instance of NSData being returned to you.  I think what is happening is your request is being sent, and you are timing out waiting for a response.  Then you are attempting to use that response and it is not initialized (you never see if `response == nil`).  I would look at Implementing the NSURLConnection Delegate and handling the request asynchronously via the connection management methods.